# Weights transfer from one model to another model with different layer architecture

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I have a CNN network with three layers and after fitting the model, weights are saved on disk. The second time I load the weights, but this time model is increased with a layer. So it is now 4 layer network. Is it possible to transfer model weights with the different architecture? If yes then how? I am using keras for development.

For me it shows error: 'You are trying to load a weight file containing 3 layers into a model with 4 layers'.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I have not tried this, but it should be possible by using the layer.get_weights() and layer.set_weights(weights) methods.

```
weights = old_model_layer.get_weights()
new_model_layer.set_weights(weights)
```

See https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/ for more info.

Comment: surely we can do that. I have done weight transfer on layer level. I was trying to work on model weight transfer without architecture difference. I guess for now there is no way to extend an architecture with using model weights. We have to use layer weights for extension.

Comment: What about the creating another Model instance that is based on the old model?

For example
new_model = Model(
    inputs=[old_model.input],
    outputs=[new_model(old_model.output)]
)

Comment: I tried the same thing. I created a new model with using old model weights and bias but found that output shape of weight of each layer being different cannot incorporate a new one.  Say for example, if we have old network with 3 layers and new network with 4 layers then 4th will be initialized with default weights which will not be compatible as input will be different to 4th layer. In sequential model the input shape is given for once only. Rest the network manages itself.

Comment: Or with the functional API:

`x = old_model.output
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x) # Additional layer
model = Model(inputs=old_model.input, outputs=x)`

Then you could save it as a new model extended model that can be used on its own.

Comment: In this case I have to check it once then. Later I will reply with either solution or another question.

Comment: From the keras documentation:model.load_weights(filepath, by_name=False) loads the weights of the model from a HDF5 file (created by save_weights). By default, the architecture is expected to be unchanged. To load weights into a different architecture (with some layers in common), use by_name=True to load only those layers with the same name.

Comment: I have just used this method to import weights from a first Network to a second Network with dropout, and it worked without any problem! The only constraint to importing weights from differnet Networks is to not change the structure of learnable parameters.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a bit late at answering, but hopefully this will help somebody.

This is how I did it:

1. Use a list to store all layers:

   ```
   model_layers = []
   model_layers.append(keras.layers.Conv2D(...))
   ...
   model_layers.append(keras.layers.Dense(units=num_classes))
   model_layers.append(keras.layers.Softmax())
   ```
2. Define the source model, and add layers from the list. Load weights from the saved file:

   ```
   model = keras.Sequential()
   for layer in model_layers:
       model.add(layer)
   model.compile(...)
   model.load_weights(filename)
   ```
3. Copy the original list to a new temporary list. Clear the original list, and to it add new instances of layers required for the *target network*:

   ```
   temp_layers = model_layers.copy()
   model_layers.clear()
   model_layers.append(keras.layers.Conv2D(...))
   ...
   model_layers.append(keras.layers.Dense(units=num_classes))
   model_layers.append(keras.layers.Softmax())
   ```
4. Assuming all layers in the source network form the initial part of the target network, copy all layer references form the temporary list to `model_layers`. EXCLUDE THE CLASSIFICATION LAYERS if required. You can also restore individual layers if you know their indices:

   ```
   for i in range(len(temp_layers) - 2):
       model_layers[i] = temp_layers[i]
   ```
5. Create the new model by following step 2:

   ```
   new_model = keras.Sequential()
   for layer in model_layers:
       new_model.add(layer)
   ```
6. Add any additional layers that may be required (along with the classification layer, if required):

   ```
   new_model.add(...)
   new_model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=num_classes))
   new_model.add(keras.layers.Softmax())
   new_model.compile(...)
   ```

I realise this is not a general answer. I have mentioned the exact steps I used in my successful implementation.

Feel free to try out different variations.